# Two wordpress sites for a single domain

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to test out a few themes with a fresh WordPress site. Currently our website xxx.com is running on WordPress, can I create another WordPress site for the same domain without any other data slowing it down. We are facing issues with our current DIVI theme. I know we can do a live preview, but we would like to test how it would look brand new .

Answer (score 0):

You can install WordPress on a sub-directory or create a new sub-domain alongside the main domain to host the other WordPress site.

Another alternative might be to create a multisite network, [check this guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/)